# how to access local Jenkins server remotely outside the local network?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, reverse-proxy

I am trying to access my local Jenkins server outside my local network using socketXp. when I click on the link getting from the socketXP it shows Jenkins login page that is good but when I login into that page it shows localhost txt and empty page  instead of Jenkins home page.